# Append spatstat intensity outputs across tesselated surface (derived from shapefile) back to SpatialPolygonsDataFrame for plotting in R

Tags: r, geospatial, spatstat

Anyone have advice for retaining (or appending) attributes from a Spatial Polygons Data Frame *after* conversion to an owin object for pattern analysis in Spatstat?

Using spatstat to calculate point intensities across a tesselated surface.  No issue with this except I lose the polygon labels when I convert the Spatial Polygons Data Frame to an owin object (and subsequently a tess object).  See sample code.  Thanks!

````
SF <- readOGR(dsn="D:/",layer="sf")
class(SF) # "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"

# Convert SpatialPolygonsDataFrame to OWIN object for use in spatstat package

y <- as(SF, "SpatialPolygons")
p <- slot(y, "polygons")
v <- lapply(p, function(z) { SpatialPolygons(list(z)) })
winlist <- lapply(v, as.owin)

# establish window needed for creating tesseslated surface
SF2 <- as(SF, "owin")

# create tesselates surface
e <-tess(tiles = winlist, window = SF2)

## compute counts and density values, across tessellated area, of point data 

# B - point pattern object created from *.csv of point locations

QB   <- quadratcount(B, tess = e)  # tally counts of 'biotic pseudo-variables' by tess tiles
Qi.B <- intensity(QB)  # Compute intensity

# Plot results
plot(intensity(QB, image=TRUE), las=1, main=NULL) # plot tess units using intensity for legend
plot(B, pch=20, cex=0.5, col="white", add=TRUE)```
````

Answer (score 1):

You will need to manually extract the polygon labels from the `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` object `SF`  as a character vector, and then assign them to the names of the tiles in the tessellation object `e`.

To extract the polygon labels you can probably type `nama <- rownames(SF)` but it depends which labels you require.

There are two ways to assign the tile names:

1. Assign names to the list of tiles before creating the tessellation. In the command `e <- tess(tiles=winlist, window=SF2)`, if `names(winlist)` is not `NULL` then the names will be retained as the names of the tiles. So you could first do `names(winlist) <- nama` and then `e <- tess(tiles=winlist, window=SF2)`.
2. Assign tile names after creating the tessellation using `"tilenames<-"`,as in `tilenames(e) <- nama` where `nama` is a character vector.

In either case, once the tiles of `e` have names, the results of calculations such as `Qi.B` will also have these names.

Comment: I used your first solution.  However, I needed to obtain polygon labels from the values of a particular column ('x'), instead of the rownames(), so extracted from dataframe  
`SF.df <- as.data.frame(SF)
nama <- SF.df$x`